# How to remap single key on bluetooth keyboard with Ubuntu Touch?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, bluetooth, keyboard-layout, emacs

I'm using a bluetooth keyboard with Ubuntu Touch (N7), it connects fine but its single <kbd>Alt</kbd> key sends the key code for <kbd>AltGr</kbd>. I need it to be mapped to <kbd>Alt</kbd> / <kbd>L_Alt</kbd> (Emacs standard Meta key, as atm I have no Meta key). Emacs documentation says that one should do this sort of key mapping within Linux and not within Emacs.

The tutorials I've read for desktop Ubuntu reference *xmodmap* for basic key mapping. *xmodmap* isn't installed in Touch although it's available via apt-get as part of the X11-utils, although again it's not clear to me how much use X11 is with Touch generally (same for *xkb* and console-setup). I may be misunderstanding things, but the maliit mappings seem to be only for the onscreen keyboard. I also poked around the Android partition as I assume it's actually handing the bluetooth input, but wasn't sure how to experiment with the keymappings I found there when I couldn't mount the partition RW using the usual `sudo mount -o remount,rw`.

This should be a small fix somewhere - can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

Your question seems to match to this bug report: 1529049

See https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu-keyboard/+bug/1529049